# Null Exception - don't know why

Tags: android, exception, null

well i don't understand why i'm getting a Null Exception in my code  :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.lista_comunidade, null);
        }
        Message o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.result_name);
            TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.result_second_line);
            //bt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 10);
            t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 10);
            bt.setTextColor(-1);
            tt.setTextColor(-1);
            tt.setTextColor(-1);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.result_icon);

            iv.setImageResource(R.id.result_icon);
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(o.getTitle());
            }
            if (bt != null) {
                bt.setText("Data: " + o.getDate().toString());

                }
            if(t != null){
                t.setText(o.getLink().toString());
            }
            }


        return v;
    }
}
```

My catlog says that :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(  757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(  757): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(  757):        at com.warriorpoint.androidxmlsimple.MessageList
 $SiteAdapter.getView(MessageList.java:182)
```

Line 182 is :

```
 TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
```

And i have this in my xml :

```
  <TextView android:text="@string/Text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></TextView>
```

What i'm missing? thanks

Comment: TextView01 vs TextView1?

Comment: Exactly, thanks! How the TextView01 got there? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 182 is `TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);`
The id in your layout is `@+id/textView1`

It seems that you have TextView01 elsewhere in your resources (allowing the code to compile), but not within the current layout.

Comment: Exactly, as BlackRider said! Thanks to both!